# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't detect BT devices

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Lenovo B5400 with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot.
My bluetooth works well under Win but with Ubuntu it is not able to detect any device. `hcitool scan` does a scan but doesn't detect anything

`hciconfig --all:`

`BD Address: A4:DB:30:9E:43:BB  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:901 acl:0 sco:0 events:42 errors:0
    TX bytes:994 acl:0 sco:0 commands:42 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'ubuntu-0'
    Class: 0x700100
    Service Classes: Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xb
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x8723
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)`

`rfkill list
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

Do you see any anomalies?

Comment: No anomalies. Check `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` for errors. Also see [bug #1284649 - 
bluetooth devices no longer connect to the system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1284649)

Answer (score -1):

Workaround: You need to have Windows installed. Start Windows, then switch OFF bluetooth, shut down. Start Ubuntu, switch on bluetooth. Now you should be able to see BT devices.

Comment: This works only in case the firmware is not installed in Ubuntu. It is easier to install firmware.

Comment: Preposterous: suggest to install windows? on this forum?